# Command to display last directory with a special file

Tags: bash, grep, cut

I have a directory with this structure:

```
Fruitables
├── Fruits
│   ├── Grapes
│   │   └── Muscat Grape
│   │       ├── Moscato Giallo
│   │       │   └── information.txt
│   │       └── Muscat Ottonel
│   │           └── information.txt
│   └── Mangoes
│       ├── Ataulfo Mango
│       │   └── information.txt
│       └── Tommy Atkins Mango
│           └── information.txt
└── Vegetables
    └── Potatoes
        ├── Ratte Potato
        │   └── information.txt
        └── Yukon Gold Potato
            └── information.txt
```

Some of the information.txt files have the String: "Special Fruit or Vegetable" .. What I want is to display the directory that contains a information.txt file with that string

I tried this:

```
shopt -s extglob
shopt -s globstar
grep -H 'Special Fruit or Vegetable' @(Fruitables)/**/*.txt | cut -d: -f1
```

This is the output:

```
Fruitables/Fruits/Grapes/Muscat Grape/Moscato Giallo/information.txt
Fruitables/Fruits/Mangoes/Ataulfo Mango/information.txt
Fruitables/Vegetables/Potatoes/Ratte Potato/information.txt
```

I want to display the last directory only, like this:

```
Moscato Giallo
Ataulfo Mango
Ratte Potato
```

Comment: I think you should look at dirname and basename

Answer (score 0):

Using `find` and `grep`:

```
find Fruitables -type f -name '*.txt' -exec sh -c '
  for path; do
    if grep -q "Special Fruit or Vegetable" "$path"; then
      dirname=${path%/*}             # strip filename suffix
      printf "%s\n" "${dirname##*/}" # strip path prefix and print it
    fi
  done
' sh {} +
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. How about using `awk` for a final touch:

```
shopt -s globstar
grep -H 'Special Fruit or Vegetable' Fruitables/**/*.txt | cut -d: -f1 | awk -F/ '{f=NF-1; print $f}'
```

Output:

```
Ratte Potato
Moscato Giallo
Ataulfo Mango
```

The `awk` command extracts the second field from the last by splitting the line with a slash.

Comment: grep has -l, no need for `cut`

Answer (score 0):

Not POSIX compatible, but a bit safer on the file names:

```
grep -rlZ 'Special Fruit or Vegetable' --include 'information.txt' ./ |  
  xargs -0 dirname -z | 
  xargs -0 -n1 basename
```

- `-r` recursively search all directories
- `-l` return filenames with match instead of matching lines
- `-Z` separate filenames with null instead of newline/:
- `--include 'information.txt'` - search only files with name information.txt
- `xargs -0 dirname -z` - run dirname with the found files, output a null after each dirname (`-z`)
- `xargs -0 -n1 basename` - run basename with one argument (-n1) as many times needed.

POSIX variant:

```
find ./ -name 'information.txt' \
    -exec grep -q 'Special Fruit or Vegetable' {} \; 
    -exec sh -c 'basename "$(dirname "{}")"' \;
```

- `-name 'information.txt'` - search for files named information.txt
- `-exec grep -q 'Special Fruit or Vegetable' {} \;` - do they match ? `-q` tells grep just to have the exit code set if a match is found
- `-exec sh -c 'basename "$(dirname "{}")"' \;` - uses shell script to extract the basename of the dirname of the file.

Answer (score -1):

Taking what you have done so far, you can put that output into a bash variable like this:

```
pathlist="$(grep -H 'Special Fruit or Vegetable' @(Fruitables)/**/*.txt | cut -d: -f1)"
```

Then, run that file through a `while read` loop and use a combination of `basename` and `dirname`:

```
while read -r path; do
    basename "$(dirname "$path")"
done <<< "pathlist"
```

The `basename` + `dirname` combination works like this example:

```
dirname foo/bar/baz # foo/bar/
basename foo/bar/   # bar
```

Depending on what you are trying to do with this output, it may be easier to put this loop in a function.

**Edit**

On second thought, it seems you can actually retrieve output on the end of the loop.  So that last line of the loop could be `done <<< "pathlist" > out.txt`